# OpenVMS 6.1 - kill process by PID

Tags: process, openvms

How do I find the Process Identification Number(PID) and how to delete the PID. I have tried "Show Process /all" but it will show only my process. I have administrative privileges.

Comment: i'd note , while its an obscure os, i'd personally consider openvms a OS that runs on a computer of sorts - as such, its probably *on* topic for superuser... and rather cool ;p

Answer (score 10):

```
$ show system
  Pid    Process Name    State  Pri      I/O       CPU       Page flts  Pages
20200121 NAMED_SERVER    HIB      6     1651   0 00:00:00.14       794    256
...
$ stop/id=20200121
```